# List of internet explorer add-ons

Tags: c++, c, internet-explorer, registry

How can I get list of all IE add-ons programatically using c/c++?
And after that I want to disable and enable them....Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guys I have found a way how to do this.

Open "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar". This 'Toolbar' key contains CLSID of all the toolbars installed. Now you need to extract the name of toolbar in 'Default' value name of key. If you did not get name under this then query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\ for that particular CLSID. There you will get the toolbar name under 'Defalut' value name.

Comment: Knowing IE, I would be surprised if HKCU didn't hold similar keys, i.e. the toolbars that are installed only for the current user.